# Удаление элемента из вектора

Tags: c++

Пишу функцию(метод класса с полем `vector<int> v`) удаления элемента `a` из вектора `v` с контролем наличия `a` в `v`:

```
bool Erase(int a)
        {
            return find(v.begin(),v.end(),a)!=v.end() ? v.erase(find(v.begin(),v.end(),a)) : 0;
        }
```

Выдаёт:

> [Error] no match for
>   ternary 'operator?:' in '__gnu_cxx::operator!=
>
> > ((*(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >*)(& std::find<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >,
> >     ...

В чём ошибка?

Comment: может всё дело в том, что тип возвращаемый `erase` - `vector<int>::iterator` и `int` не совместимы? да и функция у Вас возвращает `bool`. Как-то не очень красиво.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что оба выражения, расположенные после условия, должны иметь общий тип, то есть должны быть приводимы к общему типу. Однако нет такого неявного конструктора преобразования для итератора, который принимает в качестве аргумента число 0.

Более того неэффективно вызывать алгоритм `std::find` два раза.

Функцию можно написать следующим образом

```
bool Erase( int value )
{ 
    auto it = std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), value );

    return it == v.end() ? false : ( v.erase( it ), true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь использовать тернарный оператор для итераторов. Этот оператор для итераторов неопределен, судя по сообщению об ошибке. Наиболее простой выход - использование классического if-then-else.